# How to insert a page number referring to the the page where the citation first appeared

Tags: biblatex

I need to insert a page number into the footnote, referring to the page where the citation first appeared.

What I've got in the footnote, for example:

> 20 ) author name, (Fn. 3) p. 11.

What I need:

> 20 ) author name, (**page 15,** Fn. 3) p. 11.

=> page 15 is the page number where the citation shows up for the first time.

I use `scrbook`, biblatex and the style is `verbose-inote`.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a label on page 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pageref` option will let you add the page number of the relevant footnote as well.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-inote, pageref=true]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde, see n. 1, p. 1.]

The default settings have a slightly different output than you show. The desired output can be obtained with a few small tweaks.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-inote, pageref=true]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  seenote = {fn\adddot},
}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                  {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
         {\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
          \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
          \addcomma\space}}
      {}%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    }}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde (p. 1, fn. 1).]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.